# can I run Jupyter Notebook recursively from the GUI created?

Tags: user-interface, recursion, jupyter-notebook, runtime-error

I was trying to call the Jupyter Notebook again by clicking on a button from the GUI generated but I'm getting this error:

```
                      Error: [WinError 206] Název nebo přípona souboru je příliš dlouhá
```

(that means, when translated into English is long path-name)
I have made it shorter but it didn't help.
The code I'm using is below:

```
def execute_jupyter_script():
    try:
        # Convert the Jupyter notebook to a Python script
        notebook_path = 'C:/Users/Documents/U2.ipynb'  # Update with your Jupyter script path
        print(f"Reading notebook from path: {notebook_path}")
        with open(notebook_path, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as notebook_file:
            notebook_content = nbformat.read(notebook_file, as_version=4)
        
        python_exporter = PythonExporter()
        python_script, _ = python_exporter.from_notebook_node(notebook_content)
        
        # Execute the Python script
        result = subprocess.run(['python', '-c', python_script], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
        
        # Display the result in the output_text_area
        output_text_area.delete('1.0', tk.END)  # Clear previous content
        output_text_area.insert(tk.END, result.stdout)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error: {e}")
        output_text_area.delete('1.0', tk.END)
        output_text_area.insert(tk.END, f"Error: {e}")
```

Comment: "that means, when translated into English is long path-name) I have made it shorter but it didn't help." So the error was no longer long path name; however, you don't tell us what the new error is?

Comment: @Wayne The error is strangely enough exactly the same though I've shortened the path.